# Change value in cell based on condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> dput(dfold)
structure(list(Person_id = c(50L, 234L, 555L), Days = c(94L, 
102L, 50L), Outocme = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Basically, if the `Days` column exceeds **100**, i would like to change the value to be exactly 100. The corresponding `Outcome` should be equal to 0.

On the other hand, if the outcome is already 0 (does not matter if the `Days` column exceeds 100 days or not), the `Days` column should be equal to exactly 100.

This is what the new dataframe should look like:

```
> dput(dfnew)
structure(list(Person_id = c(50L, 234L, 555L), Days = c(94L, 
100L, 100L), Outocme = c(1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: The first row of the desired output seems to contradict your description.

Comment: How? It is below 100 days and they have the outcome, so no need to change any of those values

Comment: But theres 934 days in the first row?

Comment: @dufei wow I completely missed that, my apologies. I meant 1000 days. So sorry!

Comment: Edited it to keep the 100 day condition, but changed 934 to 94 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using Tidyverse syntax:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Person_id, ~Days, ~Outcome,
  50L,   94L,       1L,
  234L,  102L,       1L,
  555L,   50L,       0L
)

df |> 
  mutate(
    Days = if_else(Outcome == 0L, 100, Days),
    Outcome = if_else(Days > 100, 0, Outcome),
    Days = if_else(Days > 100, 100, Days)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Person_id  Days Outcome
#>       <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1        50    94       1
#> 2       234   100       0
#> 3       555   100       0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple by doing it in two steps?

```
data <- structure(list(Person_id = c(50L, 234L, 555L), 
                       Days = c(934L, 102L, 50L), 
                       Outcome = c(1L, 1L, 0L)), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

data$Days[data$Days > 100] <- 100
data$Outcome[data$Days >= 100] <- 0
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

dfold %>% 
  mutate(Days = case_when(Days > 100 ~ 100, 
                          Outocme == 0 ~ 100, 
                          Days < 100 & Outocme == 1 ~ Days), 
         Outocme = case_when(Days == 100 ~ 0, 
                             TRUE ~ Outocme))
  Person_id Days Outocme
1        50   94       1
2       234  100       0
3       555  100       0
```